# how does npm run work?

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, sh

What happens when I type `npm run <command>`?
Is the **<command>** passed to the **sh** shell, like:

```
sh -c <command>
```

with additional local variables added to the shell, ie a path to the `node_modules/.bin`?

I thought npm works only in JavaScript universe by using node, but it seems there's a lot more going on out there. How `&` and `&&` are handled? Is *globstar* safe to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npm run-script <command>` uses `sh -c` to run the command, and `cmd /d /s /c` on windows. ([source](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/33ad728dfd7b81fcfd5b8ecc0609a582a4a57567/lib/utils/lifecycle.js#L216)) It is run by [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

`npm env` lists the environment that npm uses when it runs commands. The [documentation](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/doc/misc/npm-scripts.md#environment) lists some of the things it adds to the environment. This includes everything from `package.json`, the `PATH` additions you mentioned and more.

`&`and `&&` are handled by the shell, but `spawn` is waiting for the process to end, even when it is put in the background by `&`. `&&` is working as you are used to in `sh`.

*globstar* will work as you expect, except on Windows where you have *wildcards* instead.

Comment: Sidenote regarding ´node_modules/.bin´: Under unix, the folder contains symlink to the modules .js-scripts. Under Windows, they contain .cmd files which cal the .js-scripts with node.

Comment: This it outdated. At least for `npm 8.0.0.` doesn't have "env" command. And link is broken.