# NodeJS: NOT able to set PERCY_TOKEN via package script with start-server-and-test

Tags: javascript, cypress, yarnpkg, visual-testing, percy

I have been trying really hard to set the `PERCY_TOKEN` on a local test run according the official [guideline from percy](https://docs.percy.io/docs/local-development) and trigger it via `yarn`.

The guideline says:

```
$ PERCY_TOKEN=aaabbbcccdddeeefff PERCY_BRANCH=local npm test
```

My attempt right now looks like this:

> package.json

```json
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts -r @cypress/instrument-cra start",
    "start:silent": "BROWSER=none yarn start",
    "start:server": "start-server-and-test start:silent http://localhost:3000",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "envGenerateExample": "cat .env | sed 's/=.*/=/g' > .env.example",
    "jest:test": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen",
    "cy:run": " 'yarn start:server './node_modules/.bin/cypress run'",
    "cy:open": "yarn start:server './node_modules/.bin/cypress open'",
    "cy:ci": "yarn start:server cy:chrome",
    "cy:chrome": "cypress run --browser chrome --record",
    "percy:exec": "yarn percy exec -- cypress run",
    "cy:percy": "yarn start:server percy:exec",
    "percy:local": "PERCY_TOKEN=$(grep 'PERCY_TOKEN.*' .env | sed 's/.*=//'); PERCY_BRANCH=local;",
    "cy:percy:local": "yarn percy:local && yarn start:server percy:exec"
  },
...
```

```sh
$ yarn cy:percy:local

Compiled successfully!

You can now view playground in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.163:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.

...

> playground@0.2.0 percy:exec /Users/norfeldt/Repos/playground
> yarn percy exec -- cypress run

warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
$ /Users/norfeldt/Repos/playground/node_modules/.bin/percy exec cypress run
 ›   Warning: Skipping visual tests. PERCY_TOKEN was not provided.
...
```

## TL;DR solution

> package.json

```json
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts -r @cypress/instrument-cra start",
    "start:silent": "BROWSER=none yarn start",
    "start:server": "start-server-and-test start:silent http://localhost:3000",
    ...
    "percy:local": "PERCY_TOKEN=$(grep 'PERCY_TOKEN.*' .env | sed 's/.*=//') PERCY_BRANCH=local yarn start:server 'percy exec cypress run'"
  },
...
```

Comment: Is there a reason the token isn't hard-coded? Especially locally with several projects, the shell can always only have one token at a time. I'm looking for a way to hard code it in order to avoid setting it anew each time I change the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yarn internally uses `sh` to execute the commands given in the scripts (`cmd` in case of windows) - [Source](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/a4708b29ac74df97bac45365cba4f1d62537ceb7/src/cli/commands/run.js#L136). This is very similar to what [npm does as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35733742/8266093).

Here `&&` is handled by a shell, so your command `yarn percy:local && yarn start:server percy:exec` is run as 2 separate child processes. This means `yarn percy:local` runs in a process and sets the env variables as desired in its context but the second process which is running `yarn start:server percy:exec` has no idea about the env variables set by process 1.

Lets see how OS X handles this:

1. With `&&`

```
sh -c 'PERCY_TOKEN=asdfasdf; PERCY_BRANCH=local' &&  sh -c 'echo $PERCY_TOKEN'
```

This prints nothing

2. Without `&&`

```
sh -c 'PERCY_TOKEN=asdfasdf; PERCY_BRANCH=local echo $PERCY_TOKEN'
```

This prints `asdfasdf`

I think removing the `&&` in the `cy:percy:local` should fix your issue.

**Edit: Solution for your particular situation as discussed in comments**

As explained in the 2nd point of this answer: stackoverflow.com/a/37141993/8266093 I would suggest you run this script in the format `ENV_KEY1=value1 ENV_KEY2=value2 command` which in your case becomes `PERCY_TOKEN=$(grep 'PERCY_TOKEN.*' .env | sed 's/.*=//') PERCY_BRANCH=local yarn percy exec cypress run`. Along with this, you can add your start-server yarn command as well if running it separately is not a solution for you.

Comment: It gives the same result with and without the `&&`

Comment: I think it's the `start-server-and-test` that is causing the issue

Comment: this does not work either `"cy:percy:local": "yarn start:server 'yarn percy:local; yarn percy:exec'"`

Comment: I can't comment on `yarn start:server`, let's remove the unknowns, can you run it as 2 separate commands? In one do `yarn start:server` and in the next do `yarn percy:local yarn percy:exec`. This does work for me in OS X.
Note: If `yarn start:server` is a long-running process, better run it as a background process or run it in the different thread / different terminal.

Comment: I made another script `"percy:run": "yarn percy:local; yarn percy:exec"` and did a `yarn start` in one terminal and a `yarn percy:run` in another. It still says that the token is not set

Comment: As a check can you try running `PERCY_TOKEN=asdfasdf PERCY_BRANCH=local yarn percy exec -- cypress run`? This has env vars and run commands in the same script. Do not put `;` between variables.

Comment: `$ PERCY_TOKEN=$(grep 'PERCY_TOKEN.*' .env | sed 's/.*=//') PERCY_BRANCH=local yarn percy exec cypress run` works fine from the terminal

Comment: Yeah, pass env vars as part of the command instead of running it as a separate yarn script. When run separately they run in two isolated processes.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: As explained in the 2nd point of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37141993/8266093 I would suggest you run this script in the format `ENV_KEY1=value1 ENV_KEY2=value2 command` which in your case becomes  `PERCY_TOKEN=$(grep 'PERCY_TOKEN.*' .env | sed 's/.*=//') PERCY_BRANCH=local yarn percy exec cypress run` which as you just mentioned is working fine.

Comment:  I finally got it working with `"percy:local": "PERCY_TOKEN=$(grep 'PERCY_TOKEN.*' .env | sed 's/.*=//') PERCY_BRANCH=local yarn start:server 'percy exec cypress run'"` - if you add that to your answer I'll mark it as the solution.